# How long it takes to index a 9.7G zim file using kiwix-index?

Tags: mediawiki

I am trying to use [*kiwix*](http://www.kiwix.org) to server an offline wikipedia. I have got a 9.7G zim file `wikipedia_en_all_nopic_01_2012_db.zim`. To make search possible,

```
kiwix-index wikipedia_en_all_nopic_01_2012_db.zim wikipedia.idx
```

The official site just says it will take long time, but how long? Several hours, one day, a week? Have anybody done this before?

```
Processor: i7 4770
Platform:  ubuntu 13.04
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it for a 100-MB zim file with Kiwix. it took about 10 minutes or so. my system performance was: 
RAM: 1 GB
CPU: 1.6 GHz Intel Atom
OS: Windows

so with your system, for a 10-GB file, I guess it will take a couple of hours to finish.